# Understanding Sequelize database migrations and seeds

Tags: node.js, database, sequelize.js, database-migration

I'm trying to wrap my head around Sequelize's migrations and how they work together with seeds (or maybe migrations and seeds in general).
I set up everything to get the migrations working.

First, lets create a `users` table:

```
// migrations/01-create-users.js
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable("Users", {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
      },
      updatedAt: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable("Users");
  }
};
```

Fine. If I want to seed an (admin) user, I can do this as follows:

```
// seeders/01-demo-user.js
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.bulkInsert(
      "Users",
      [
        {
          email: "demo@demo.com"
        }
      ],
      {}
    );
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.bulkDelete("Users", null, {});
  }
};
```

Then to make the magic happen, I do:

```
$ sequelize db:migrate
```

Which creates the `users` table in the database. After running the migrations, seeding is the next step, so:

```
$ sequelize db:seed:all
```

Tataa, now I have a user in the `users` database. Great.

But now I want to add `firstname` to the `users` table, so I have to add another migration:

```
// migrations/02-alter-users.js
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.addColumn("Users", "firstname", {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.removeColumn("Users", "firstname");
  }
};
```

Running migrations again would only run the second one because it was saved in the database that the first one was already executed. But by default sequelize re-runs all seeders. So should I adjust the `seeders/01-demo-user.js` or change the default behavior and also store the seeders in the DB and create a new one that just updates the `firstname`?

What if `firstname` couldn't be `null`, then running migrations first and then the old version of `seeders/01-demo-user.js` would throw an error because `firstname` can't be `null`.

Re-running seeders leads to another problem: there is already a user with the `demo@demo.com` email. Running it a second time would duplicate the user. Or do I have to check for things like this in the seeder?

Previously, I just added the user-account in the migration so I could be sure when it was added to the DB and when I had to update it. But someone told me I was doing it all wrong and that I have to use seeders for tasks like this.

Any help/insights much appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I am having the same issues.

Comment: Not really. Right now, _if_ I'm using seeders I also store in the DB that I ran them so they won't run a second time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my opinion, a seeder is something, that is intended to run only once, while the migration is something that you add layer by layer to your DB structure continuously.

I would use seeders for populating some lookups or other data that most likely is not going to change, or test data. In the `sequelize` [docs](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/migrations/#creating-the-first-seed) it's said that

> Seed files are some change in data that can be used to populate database table with sample data or test data.

If you want to make some dynamic data updates when data structure has already changed, you can run raw queries directly in your migrations if needed. So, if you, for instance, added some column in the `up` method, you can update the rows in the DB according to your business logic, e.g.:

```js
// Add column, allow null at first
await queryInterface.addColumn("users", "user_type", {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: true
});

// Update data
await queryInterface.sequelize.query("UPDATE users SET user_type = 'simple_user' WHERE is_deleted = 0;");

// Change column, disallow null
await queryInterface.changeColumn("users", "user_type", {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
});
```

There is also an interesting [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rails-oceania/BmTqmoiiP-k) on this topic in Google Groups.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  Just ran into this same confusion.  perfectly put.  Thank you

Comment: The Sequelize [docs](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/migrations.html#creating-first-seed) confuse the issue when they state: "To manage all data migrations you can use seeders".  It simply isn't true.  There are many reasons one should update data in migration files, rather than seeds.  in an established application, it seems like updating data in migration files should happen much more often than in seeders.

Comment: I'm a little confused how things work if I write some migrations and a seeder, which relies on those migrations and then add more migrations that make the seeders invalid with new columns...

Sure, I can update the data in the new migration, but what happens if I want to create a new db? The new migration relies on the seeder being run first... I think what should really happen is there be a specific order of migrations and seeders.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience migrations change structure.  Seeders... seed data.  Recently I was on a project that didn't have seeders configured.  https://sequelize.org/master/manual/migrations.html#seed-storage.  This will allow you to setup a file so your data isn't seeded more than once.  Migration configuration is right there as well.

Answer (score 2):

Hi try with bulkUpdate...

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) =>  queryInterface.addColumn(
        'Users',
        'user_type',
        {
          type: Sequelize.STRING,
          allowNull: false,
        }
      ).then(()=>
        queryInterface.bulkUpdate('Users', {
            user_type: 'simple_user',
        }, {
            is_deleted : 0,
        })
      ),

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => 
    queryInterface.removeColumn('Users', 'user_type')
};
```